# How to save plot generated by pairs.panels from R's psych library in Jupyter

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, jupyter, psych

I'm using R's `psych` library and I'm plotting correlation pairs on a Jupyter notebook using its `pairs.panels` function.

I tried using ggplot's `ggsave` function to save the plot but it wouldn't work. The error says:

`Error in ggsave(filename = "correlation-pairs.png", : plot should be a ggplot2 plot`

Is there a way to save the output of `pairs.panels`?

Comment: As far as I can see, `pairs.panels` doesn't use `ggplot2` package. So `ggsave` won't work.  You probably need `png()` and `dev.off()` functions.

Comment: @Pascal, you see [far enough](https://github.com/cran/psych/blob/master/R/pairs.panels.R). :) No ggplot2 code there. FWIW, Adler, you can use `pdf()`, among other fector based files, as well.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal and Roman! :)